# Finding eigenvector of $ \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & B \\ B & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right] $

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

> $A \in M^{2n\times 2n}(\mathbb{R})$ $$A = \left[  \begin{matrix}   0 &
>  B \\   B & 0   \end{matrix} \right] $$ where $B$ is symmetric matrix
>   ($B^T=B$).
>
> Is it possible to find a pair $(\lambda, x)$ where $\lambda$ is an
>   eigenvalue and $x$ is an eigenvector and $|\lambda|$ is highest among
>   all eigenvalues. If you can use only power iteration? If it is possible then how you should do it?

I think that it is not possible. 
Here is the intuition I have:

Let's suppose that we can solve the task. Then we can take arbitrary $x_0$ and  build a sequence of $x_i = A^ix_0$. However the structure of A implicates that if $x_0=[x_0^1, x_0^2]$ then every iteration swap $x_0^1$ and $x_0^2$, so the sequences  $B^nx_0^1$  and $B^nx_0^2$ should have the same limit, however since $x_0$ is totally arbitrary vector then only possible limit is $0$ which is not an eigenvector.

Am I right and how to prove it properly?

Comment: $A = B \otimes \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product. You can go on to use the results about how Kronecker products inherit their parent's ( factors ) eigenvalues.

Comment: Then $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ eigenvalues can be calculated simply with a 2 point FFT as they are the simplest possible lazy filter ( circulant matrix ).

Comment: The eigenvalues of $A$ are the singular values of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $(\mu, v)$ is an eigenpair for $B$, then
$$
A \pmatrix{x\\x}= \mu \pmatrix{x\\x}\qquad
A\pmatrix{x\\-x}= -\mu \pmatrix{x\\x}
$$
The fact that these eigenvalues of $A$ have the same magnitude presents an issue.